# error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using android jdk1.8.0_05 and I get the error:

'to_string' was not declared in this scope

My code line is

```
for (j = 1; j <= MAX_NUM_OF_TRAIN; j++){
    string strNum = std::to_string(j);
...
}
```

Does JNI supports to_string? 
What would be the best way to do it in a 'for' loop?

Comment: Do you build with C++11 enabled?

Comment: Read the answer(s) in the linked question.